# snapping not working correctly

Tags: vertices, snapping

I'm pretty new to blender, and am having trouble getting snapping to function properly. In object mode the snap to grid function works fine, but all the others fail to snap unless I get the origin of the selected object close to my target (i.e., if I have snap to vertex selected I can move vertices directly on top of each other with no snap, but if I move the object to the origin is close to the target vertex, it will suddenly snap vertex to vertex. same with face, edge, etc.). I have tried starting from a new file, restarting blender, and I made sure proportional editing was off. Am I missing something obvious? Thanks!

Comment: What version of blender are you using?

Comment: @Jesse I'm using version 2.91.0

Comment: Under the snap menu there is a section called "Snap with" It gives you the options: Closest, Active, Median, and Center. Have you tried changing those option to see if you get the result you want? It sounds like you may be on Active or Center. I find closest to be the most useful setting for most general tasks.

Comment: @Jesse I just figured it out. Turns out you have to mouse over the vertex you want to snap to not just get to two vertices close to each other, and since I'm used to grabbing objects by the center of their volume just out of habit it created the illusion that it was because I was getting the origin near the target vertex. Thanks so much for your help though!

Comment: @jesse I really was missing something obvious haha.

Comment: Yeah, understandable. I used sketcup before blender and the snapping was like you describe. Blender felt very weird at first.